# Are new characters possible with a custom keyboard in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension

In iOS 8, Apple has given developers the ability to create custom keyboards. In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html), Apple states that you should create a new keyboard if you want to support a language that iOS does not currently support. Therefore, if you are able to support new languages, are you able to create a keyboard that contains new emoji characters? I would assume that by Apple stating that you can support a new language, they would expect there to be custom characters involved. If including custom characters is possible, how would other devices (even if only other devices running iOS 8) display the new characters?

Comment: FYI - This question would be better asked on the Apple developer forums for two reasons. No one here probably knows yet and you are violating the NDA you agreed to with Apple.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for letting me know! I am careful about the NDA, but I saw this link: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/apple-lifted-beta-nda/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1), a custom keyboard takes touch or gesture input (or whatever else, really) and produces `NSString` objects for insertion into text fields or other text-based controls.

So, the answer to your question is mostly no -- a keyboard can input only things that the system sees as text.

How, then, does Apple talk of using this feature to add new keyboard languages? There are lots of scripts covered by Unicode. Some of them even have glyphs in the fonts that ship with iOS, but aren't covered by an Apple-provided keyboard. (For example, the [Canadian Aboriginal](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/unified_canadian_aboriginal_syllabics/utf8test.htm) alphabet.) A third-party keyboard could cover such a script to provide support for a language that doesn't have an Apple keyboard.

There are also all sorts of scripts in Unicode not covered by the built in fonts in iOS, including many real languages as well as informal standards not recognized by the Unicode consortium -- there you'll find Klingon, Quenya, and Dr. Suess' *On Beyond Zebra*. A third-party keyboard could also add support for such scripts, but only if the user has appropriate fonts installed for rendering them.

So if you want to invent your own Emoji, you'll have to provide:

- a custom keyboard
- a font with your characters (at code points not otherwise used in Unicode)
- a community of users / vendors of other software who know the mapping of code points to your invented glyphs
- and are using your custom font in other apps and other platforms.

(If you just want to add something like the newly announced Unicode 7.0 emoji, you can skip step 3.)

Comment: Hi Rickster,  I have created a keyboard extension. I used a special font(Dyslexic) for displaying character in keyboard. Now i need that when a user type using my keyboard, character will be display in the same font(My Custom font) instead of default apple font. how it could be. If unicode is a way to do so, how can i get uniqode for "Dyslexic Font". Please help me in this.

Comment: If what I am understanding is right, then supporting new languages is still not possible and its pretty bad from Apple. I had to create the complete Notes app with the custom OS keyboard since iOS7 to help revive our ancient Coptic (Egyptian) language, called Coptic Notes on the App store. Unicode is also not supported http://www.copticnotes.com http://www.facebook.com/CopticNotes and I was hoping that with the new keyboard extensions, I could do this.

Comment: @Surjeet any update on this please tell me its required ...thanks