# Customising the keyboard system wide for new language in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, keyboard, xcode6

From iOS 8 it is possible to add custom keyboard from our application which can be used system wide.

I need to create such a keyboard which can be used to input custom characters(a new language). I have these characters as images.

How can I use these images to input as characters from the keyboard into a textfield?

Please suggest any tips, link, methods etc..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly, a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255631/are-new-characters-possible-with-a-custom-keyboard-in-ios-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put custom images in text fields because they are used to input text, not images.

The only possibility is custom font with images, but it will not be available system-wide and text fields are under control of the host app. For the available methods to insert characters see [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKeyInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIKeyInput)

Comment: Then how a new language is added?

Comment: They all add characters in Unicode, even the hieroglyphs and emoji. Here is some info: http://www.unicode.org/standard/WhatIsUnicode.html You can search for your language here http://www.unicode.org/glossary/index.html

Comment: You can search for the characters of you language in the Unicode http://unicode-table.com
(Glossary link is wrong, my bad)

Comment: But my requirement is to add an entirely new keyboard for an entirely new language with new characters.

Comment: Well, you can't do that system-wide, but only inside your own app. Apple provided this Custom Keyboard API to give ability to create new keyboards, not the languages. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow [this guide](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/). Actually I've found plenty of similar guides [using google](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ios%20write%20own%20keyboard).
Also [Apple's custom keyboard guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html) might be helpful

Comment: None of these links explain how to input the image as characters.

Comment: well, instead of setting button titles in the `createButtons` func, you could set images like this: `button.setImage(UIImage(named: "button1"), forState: .Normal)`

Comment: And you still need the characters to put into text fields when you tap your custom buttons.